# Parcelable in Custom Modal Class throw StackOverflow Error

Tags: android, android-fragments, parcelable, stack-overflow

I want to pass the object from fragment to Activity.

This is my Modal Class ::

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class TopupProSectionName 
{
    private String sectionName;
    public ArrayList<Products> topupProductList ;
    private TopupProSectionName topupProSectionName;
    private TopupProSectionName.Products topupProducts;

    public TopupProSectionName(String name, ArrayList<Products> topupProductList)
    {
        super();
        this.sectionName = name;
        this.topupProductList = topupProductList;
    }

    public TopupProSectionName() 
    {
        topupProductList = new ArrayList<Products>();
        topupProSectionName=new TopupProSectionName();
        topupProducts = topupProSectionName.new Products();
    }

    public String getsectionName() {
        return sectionName;
    }
    public void setsectionName(String sectionName) {
        this.sectionName = sectionName;
    }

    public ArrayList<Products> getTopupProductList() {
        return topupProductList;
    }

    public void setTopupProductList(ArrayList<Products> topupProductList) {
        this.topupProductList = topupProductList;
    }

    public Products getTopupProducts() {
        return topupProducts;
    }
    public void setTopupProducts(TopupProSectionName.Products tp) {
        this.topupProducts = tp;
    }

    public class Products implements Parcelable
    {
        String systemServiceID;
        String systemServiceName;
        String productID;
        String productCode;
        String productName;
        String productDescription;
        String productType;
        String batchID;
        String minValue;
        String maxValue;
        String ImageURL;
        String surchargeType;
        String surchargeValue;

        public String getSystemServiceID()
        {
            return systemServiceID;
        }
        public void setSystemServiceID(String id)
        {
            this.systemServiceID=id;
        }
        public String getSystemServiceName()
        {
            return systemServiceName;
        }
        public void setSystemServiceName(String name)
        {
            this.systemServiceName=name;
        }

        public void setProductDesc(String productDesc)
        {
            this.productDescription=productDesc;
        }
        public String getProductDesc()
        {
            return productDescription;
        }

        public void setBatchID(String batchID)
        {
            this.batchID=batchID;
        }
        public String getBatchID()
        {
            return batchID;
        }

        public void setMinValue(String minValue)
        {
            this.minValue=minValue;
        }
        public String getminValue()
        {
            return minValue;
        }

        public void setMaxValue(String maxValue)
        {
            this.maxValue=maxValue;
        }
        public String getMaxValue()
        {
            return maxValue;
        }

        public String getProductID()
        {
            return productID;
        }
        public void setProductID(String ID)
        {
            productID=ID;
        }

        public String getProductCode() {
            return productCode;
        }
        public void setProductCode(String productCode) {
            this.productCode = productCode;
        }
        public String getProductName()
        {
            return productName;
        }
        public void setProductName(String name)
        {
            productName=name;
        }

        public String getProductType()
        {
            return productType;
        }
        public void setProductType(String type)
        {
            productType=type;
        }

        public String getImageURL()
        {
            return ImageURL;
        }
        public void setImageURL(String ImageURL)
        {
            this.ImageURL=ImageURL;
        }
        public String getSurchargeValue() {
            return surchargeValue;
        }
        public void setSurchargeValue(String surchargeValue) {
            this.surchargeValue = surchargeValue;
        }
        public String getSurchargeType() {
            return surchargeType;
        }
        public void setSurchargeType(String surchargeType) {
            this.surchargeType = surchargeType;
        }

        private Products(Parcel in) {
            topupProducts.setSystemServiceID(in.readString());
            topupProducts.setSystemServiceName(in.readString());
            topupProducts.setProductID(in.readString());
            topupProducts.setProductCode(in.readString());
            topupProducts.setProductDesc(in.readString());
            topupProducts.setProductName(in.readString());
            topupProducts.setProductDesc(in.readString());
            topupProducts.setProductType(in.readString());
            topupProducts.setBatchID(in.readString());
            topupProducts.setMinValue(in.readString());
            topupProducts.setMaxValue(in.readString());
            topupProducts.setImageURL(in.readString());
            topupProducts.setSurchargeType(in.readString());
            topupProducts.setSurchargeValue(in.readString());
        }

        public Products() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        /*
         * you can use hashCode() here.
         */
        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        /*
         * Actual object Serialization/flattening happens here. You need to
         * individually Parcel each property of your object.
         */
        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
            parcel.writeString(topupProducts.getSystemServiceID());
            parcel.writeString(topupProducts.getSystemServiceName());
            parcel.writeString(topupProducts.getProductID());
            parcel.writeString(topupProducts.getProductCode());
            parcel.writeString(topupProducts.getProductName());
            parcel.writeString(topupProducts.getProductDesc());
            parcel.writeString(topupProducts.getProductType());
            parcel.writeString(topupProducts.getBatchID());
            parcel.writeString(topupProducts.getminValue());
            parcel.writeString(topupProducts.getMaxValue());
            parcel.writeString(topupProducts.getImageURL());
            parcel.writeString(topupProducts.getSurchargeType());
            parcel.writeString(topupProducts.getSurchargeValue());
        }

        /*
         * Parcelable interface must also have a static field called CREATOR,
         * which is an object implementing the Parcelable.Creator interface.
         * Used to un-marshal or de-serialize object from Parcel.
         */
        public final Parcelable.Creator<TopupProSectionName.Products> CREATOR =
                new Parcelable.Creator<TopupProSectionName.Products>() {
            public TopupProSectionName.Products createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new TopupProSectionName.Products(in);
            }

            public TopupProSectionName.Products[] newArray(int size) {
                return new TopupProSectionName.Products[size];
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I am passing the object something like this ::

```
TopupProSectionName topupProSecName=new TopupProSectionName();
TopupProSectionName.Products Pro=topupProSecName.new Products();
Pro=listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getTopupProducts();               
startActivityForResult(new Intent(ctx,TopupDialogActivity.class).putExtra("Product",Pro), 11);
```

Receiving in the Activity ::

```
Products=(TopupProSectionName.Products) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Product");
```

Logcat ::

```
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956): java.lang.StackOverflowError
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at java.util.AbstractList.<init>(AbstractList.java:383)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:90)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:24)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectionName.java:25)
12-09 14:18:47.374: E/AndroidRuntime(28956):    at com.mobifin.subscriber.modal.TopupProSectionName.<init>(TopupProSectio
```

Any clue why this implementation went wrong?
Any Help/Suggestion will be appreciated...

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not instantiate TopupProSectionName field in TopupProSectionName class in it's Constructor. if so, it will create infinite objects as every TopupProSectionName object will contain again TopupProSectionName... use setter and getter methods to assin values to TopupProSectionName field and CREATOR field in Products class must be static...

try this... and it is self explanatory...

```
public class TopupProSectionName {
    private String sectionName;
    public ArrayList<Products> topupProductList;
    private TopupProSectionName topupProSectionName;
    private TopupProSectionName.Products topupProducts;

    public TopupProSectionName(String name, ArrayList<Products> topupProductList) {
        super();
        this.sectionName = name;
        this.topupProductList = topupProductList;
    }

    public TopupProSectionName() {
        topupProductList = new ArrayList<Products>();
        topupProducts = new TopupProSectionName.Products();
    }

    public String getsectionName() {
        return sectionName;
    }

    public void setsectionName(String sectionName) {
        this.sectionName = sectionName;
    }

    public ArrayList<Products> getTopupProductList() {
        return topupProductList;
    }

    public void setTopupProductList(ArrayList<Products> topupProductList) {
        this.topupProductList = topupProductList;
    }

    public Products getTopupProducts() {
        return topupProducts;
    }

    public void setTopupProducts(TopupProSectionName.Products tp) {
        this.topupProducts = tp;
    }

    public TopupProSectionName getTopupProSectionName() {
        return topupProSectionName;
    }

    public void setTopupProSectionName(TopupProSectionName topupProSectionName) {
        this.topupProSectionName = topupProSectionName;
    }

    public static class Products implements Parcelable {
        String systemServiceID;
        String systemServiceName;
        String productID;
        String productCode;
        String productName;
        String productDescription;
        String productType;
        String batchID;
        String minValue;
        String maxValue;
        String ImageURL;
        String surchargeType;
        String surchargeValue;

        public String getSystemServiceID() {
            return systemServiceID;
        }

        public void setSystemServiceID(String id) {
            this.systemServiceID = id;
        }

        public String getSystemServiceName() {
            return systemServiceName;
        }

        public void setSystemServiceName(String name) {
            this.systemServiceName = name;
        }

        public void setProductDesc(String productDesc) {
            this.productDescription = productDesc;
        }

        public String getProductDesc() {
            return productDescription;
        }

        public void setBatchID(String batchID) {
            this.batchID = batchID;
        }

        public String getBatchID() {
            return batchID;
        }

        public void setMinValue(String minValue) {
            this.minValue = minValue;
        }

        public String getminValue() {
            return minValue;
        }

        public void setMaxValue(String maxValue) {
            this.maxValue = maxValue;
        }

        public String getMaxValue() {
            return maxValue;
        }

        public String getProductID() {
            return productID;
        }

        public void setProductID(String ID) {
            productID = ID;
        }

        public String getProductCode() {
            return productCode;
        }

        public void setProductCode(String productCode) {
            this.productCode = productCode;
        }

        public String getProductName() {
            return productName;
        }

        public void setProductName(String name) {
            productName = name;
        }

        public String getProductType() {
            return productType;
        }

        public void setProductType(String type) {
            productType = type;
        }

        public String getImageURL() {
            return ImageURL;
        }

        public void setImageURL(String ImageURL) {
            this.ImageURL = ImageURL;
        }

        public String getSurchargeValue() {
            return surchargeValue;
        }

        public void setSurchargeValue(String surchargeValue) {
            this.surchargeValue = surchargeValue;
        }

        public String getSurchargeType() {
            return surchargeType;
        }

        public void setSurchargeType(String surchargeType) {
            this.surchargeType = surchargeType;
        }

        private Products(Parcel in) {
            setSystemServiceID(in.readString());
            setSystemServiceName(in.readString());
            setProductID(in.readString());
            setProductCode(in.readString());
            setProductDesc(in.readString());
            setProductName(in.readString());
            setProductDesc(in.readString());
            setProductType(in.readString());
            setBatchID(in.readString());
            setMinValue(in.readString());
            setMaxValue(in.readString());
            setImageURL(in.readString());
            setSurchargeType(in.readString());
            setSurchargeValue(in.readString());
        }

        public Products() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        /*
         * you can use hashCode() here.
         */
        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        /*
         * Actual object Serialization/flattening happens here. You need to
         * individually Parcel each property of your object.
         */
        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
            parcel.writeString(getSystemServiceID());
            parcel.writeString(getSystemServiceName());
            parcel.writeString(getProductID());
            parcel.writeString(getProductCode());
            parcel.writeString(getProductName());
            parcel.writeString(getProductDesc());
            parcel.writeString(getProductType());
            parcel.writeString(getBatchID());
            parcel.writeString(getminValue());
            parcel.writeString(getMaxValue());
            parcel.writeString(getImageURL());
            parcel.writeString(getSurchargeType());
            parcel.writeString(getSurchargeValue());
        }

        /*
         * Parcelable interface must also have a static field called CREATOR,
         * which is an object implementing the Parcelable.Creator interface.
         * Used to un-marshal or de-serialize object from Parcel.
         */
        public static final Parcelable.Creator<TopupProSectionName.Products> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<TopupProSectionName.Products>() {
            public TopupProSectionName.Products createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new TopupProSectionName.Products(in);
            }

            public TopupProSectionName.Products[] newArray(int size) {
                return new TopupProSectionName.Products[size];
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and create instance for Product like this...

```
  TopupProSectionName topupProSecName=new TopupProSectionName();
  TopupProSectionName.Products Pro=new TopupProSectionName.Products();
  Pro=listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getTopupProducts();               
  startActivityForResult(new Intent(ctx,TopupDialogActivity.class).putExtra("Product",Pro), 11)
```

Comment: I have tried your code,by keeping the inner class as Public Static i got the error.So i remove the static keyword and then apply your logic.But then i found the same error again.so is it necessary to keep the inner class as Public Static ???

Comment: Error==> Illegal enclosing instance specification for type TopupProSectionName.Products  This is error m getting in my Fragment.

Comment: I did the change as per you suggested but getting the same error again... :( any clue ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42782/discussion-between-gopal-rao-and-androidlearner)

Comment: did you declare Products class as static?

Comment: Yes.declared as public static